# How to solve high CPU load by apache? (ubuntu+ec2)

Tags: apache, ubuntu, apache2, cpu

I'm setup a instance in Amazon EC2, a ubuntu 10.04 server running apache2, php5 and mysql.

With less than 10 users using the system the server gets 20%, 30%, 40% of CPU load.

Using top I see in the firsts lines:

> 11121 www-data  20   0 71940  20m  11m S | 22.6 |  1.2 |  0:00.68 apache2
>   10108 www-data  20   0 72196  22m  12m S | 21.9 |  1.3 |  1:15.81 apache2
>   11122 www-data  20   0 71936  20m  11m S | 7.3  | 1.2 |  0:00.68 apache2
>   10111 www-data  20   0 72196  22m  12m S | 1.7  | 1.3 |  1:16.43 apache2

The CPU sum in this 4 lines are 53,5.

How can I see more detailed the processes?
How can I take a look into scripts running, the times it takes, the amont of processor each one consumes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

I solved the problem by installing Apache mod Status - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_status.html. There you can see each PID on what URL is used.

Hope it helps anybody...

Answer (score 3):

One way of looking at what it's doing is to use `lsof` (you may have to install it).  To see what the processes in your example are accessing you would do this:

```
lsof -p 11121,10108,11122,10111
```

This will show you all the files that process has opened.  Usually a high CPU on the Apache process is due to something the website is trying to do server side.

Comment: More generic: `pgrep -f "apache" | paste -sd, | xargs lsof -p`

Answer (score 2):

You can use strace on the parent process to get a better idea of what its doing.

Comment: Ok.. I use it.. but I want to know more about the apache process. Not only "how" it process, but what. What script are running now? How much time each script are speending from my CPU?